# Configurable xml unmarshalling in Go

Tags: xml, go, struct, unmarshalling

I am writing an xml parser which data I want to be mapped over to my own format. I can do that by using the xml.Unmarshal() and defining a struct, with the fields I want to keep.

Ie for a typical RSS feeds I would define the structure like this:

```
type ChannelRss struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"rss"`
    NewsItems []struct {
        Headline    string `xml:"title"`
        Intro       string `xml:"description"`
        ArticleID   string `xml:"guid"`
    } `xml:"channel>item"`
}
```

No problem so far. I can create a function, which accepts xml-data and returns a ChannelRss, for me to work on. But what if I want to parse several xml/rss feeds and map them in a similar fasion? I would have to create a new struct, with different configurations:

```
type TheVergeRss struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"feed"`
    NewsItems []struct {
        Headline    string `xml:"title"`
        Intro       string `xml:"content"`
        ArticleID   string `xml:"guid"`
    } `xml:"entry"`
}
```

But that leaves me with a problem, I now have 2(+) different structs, which essentially contain the same data: Headline, Intro, and ArticleID. Is there a way to return a Generic struct instead?:

Essensially I would like to put all field-tags in a configuration file. And have a function that accepts an url, accompanied with matching field-tags, and just map to a struct like this.

```
type NewsItemCollection struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    NewsItem []struct {
        Headline string
        Intro string
        ArticleID string
    }
}
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is using reflection. You can use reflect.StructOf to dynamically generate a struct with the required tags, unmarshal the xml and convert this dynamic type into a static one, for instance:

```
//define the static struct
type StaticStruct struct {
    Headline   string
    Intro      string
    ArticleID  string
}
//define a dynamic struct
dynamicType := reflect.StructOf([]reflect.StructField{
    {
      Name: "Headline",
      Type: reflect.TypeOf("str"),
      Tag:  `xml:"title"`,
    },
    {
      Name: "Intro",
      Type: reflect.TypeOf("str"),
      Tag:  `xml:"content"`,
    },
    {
      Name: "ArticleID",
      Type: reflect.TypeOf("str"),
      Tag:  `xml:"guid"`,
    },
  })
dynamicInstance := reflect.New(dynamicType)
//unmarshal content into new dynamicInstance (it's already a pointer)
xml.Unmarshal(`xml content`, dynamicInstance.Interface())
//Convert dynamic instance into a StaticStruct
staticInstance := dynamicInstance.Convert(reflect.TypeOf(&StaticStruct{})).Interface()
```

The conversion will work as `StaticStruct` has the same fields as the ones specified by the `dynamicType` ignoring struct tags